# apply gson UPPER_CAMEL_CASE for specific sub-json

Tags: java, gson, aws-sdk, amazon-dynamodb-streams

I have these messages arriving from SQS:

```
{
  "eventID": "zzz",
  "eventName": "MODIFY",
  "eventVersion": "1.1",
  "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
  "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
  "dynamodb": {
    "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1521976320,
    "Keys": {
      "key_1": {
        "S": "yyy"
      },
      "key_2": {
        "S": "xxx"
      }
    },
    "SequenceNumber": "123",
    "SizeBytes": 321,
    "StreamViewType": "KEYS_ONLY"
  },
  "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:eventSourceARN",
  "itemType": "myItem"
}
```

I want to use gson library to convert this json string into a Record object (`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.Record`) which contains  a StreamRecord object (`com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.StreamRecord`) that represents the dynamodb sub json.

problem is that the inner fields of the dynamodb object are PascalCase while the other fields are normal camelCase.

This code:

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                //.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE)
                .create();

        String json = <the json from the example above>
        Record record = gson.fromJson(json, Record.class);
        log.info("record="+record.toString());
        StreamRecord dynamodb = record.getDynamodb();
        log.info("dynamodb="+dynamodb.toString());
        Map<String, AttributeValue> keys = dynamodb.getKeys();
        log.info("keys="+keys.toString());
```

prints this log (UPPER_CAMEL_CASE commented out) :

```
record={EventID: zzz,EventName: MODIFY,EventVersion: 1.1,EventSource: aws:dynamodb,AwsRegion: us-east-1,Dynamodb: {},}
```

and then throws Null Pointer exception because the dynamoDb object is empty - because my json string is `UPPER_CAMEL_CASE`, while in the object its normal camelCase.

**I want to apply `FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE` only for the dynamodb sub json.

perhaps somehow using `FieldNamingStrategy` ?**

The json is given and I cannot change its schema.
I also can't change the fact that I get it as string.

see AWS API:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_Record.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_streams_StreamRecord.html

Answer (score 3):

You seem to want the following naming strategy:

```java
private static final Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setFieldNamingStrategy(field -> {
            if ( field.getDeclaringClass() == StreamRecord.class ) {
                return FieldNamingPolicy.UPPER_CAMEL_CASE.translateName(field);
            }
            return FieldNamingPolicy.IDENTITY.translateName(field);
        })
        .create();
```

I usually never use naming strategies in favor of the `@SerializedName` annotation though, just to be more precise when declaring mappings.